# Installing requirements.txt into virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a directory with scripts *.py that I need to compile on another computer that includes different versions of modules. I opened the terminal in that directory and have created requirements:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then I created a vertual environment and tried to installed packages from requirements.txt

```
virtualenv compilation
source compilation/bin/activate
python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It ended with this:

```
ERROR: Cannot install babel==2.7.0, gitsome==0.8.4 and pytz==2021.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested pytz==2021.1
    babel 2.7.0 depends on pytz>=2015.7
    gitsome 0.8.4 depends on pytz<2017.0 and >=2016.3

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Why is there a conflict when these packages work in non-virtual python3.6, please? What to do with that, please?

**After babel and gitsome upgrade**

```
ERROR: Cannot install babel==2.7.0, gitsome==0.8.4, pandas==1.1.5 and pytz==2016.10 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested pytz==2016.10
    babel 2.7.0 depends on pytz>=2015.7
    gitsome 0.8.4 depends on pytz<2017.0 and >=2016.3
    pandas 1.1.5 depends on pytz>=2017.2

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

**Downgrading pytz**

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pandas 1.1.5 requires pytz>=2017.2, but you have pytz 2015.7 which is incompatible.
gitsome 0.8.4 requires pytz<2017.0,>=2016.3, but you have pytz 2015.7 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed pytz-2016.10
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-8c5_ezeo'
```

Comment: Looks like babel and gitsome depend on a version of pytz that's older than the pytz that you have installed. maybe downgrade pytz to a version or --upgrade your other two packages

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try downgrading pytz

```
pip install -Iv pytz==2017.0
```

or upgrading babel and gitsome

```
sudo pip install babel --upgrade
sudo pip install gitsome --upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you, I added results to my question

Comment: if you follow this guide https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies it may help explain it better then I could, but you gotta try to get the correct verion of pytz so that everything is satisfied. But it looks l gitsome and pandas now are in conflict

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, why is the conflict only in the virtual environment?

Comment: your virtual environment is a tight-knit place for your code to function as expected where all of your dependencies are found. You can have your code work outside of the VE because other dependencies are available via pip installing outside of your VE